# Debian 6 service nginx

Tags: nginx, debian

Установлен Debian 6.
После обновления nginx перестала работать консольная команда

```
service nginx restart
```

Любая команда вида `service nginx [param]` выдает ошибку:

```
exec: 129: status: not found
```

Подскажите, как починить.

Comment: google говорит, что это связано скорее с докером, чем с nginx

Comment: Как именно обновляли nginx? Debian 6 уже два года EOL даже с учётом LTS.

Comment: Докер не установлен, так что google ошибается.

Comment: Сначала установил nginx с образов дисков дистрибутива дебиана. Все работало. Затем подключил репозиторий и обновил через apt-get upgrade

Comment: Репозиториями не ошиблись? Вдруг притянули пакеты из stable вместо явного указания на squeeze. Если не ошиблись и верно ставили пакеты squeeze - то не хочет ли ещё чего полезного обновить `apt-get dist-upgrade`? Ну и весьма советую обновиться до актуального релиза, повторюсь, squeeze очень давно уже OEL.

Comment: К сожалению мне нужен LEMP сервер именно на squeeze. nginx нормально работает, рестартует и т.д. Но именно команда service не пашет.